# How to access local files for an Azure WebSite using jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, azure

I have deployed an AngularJS application to an Azure App Service and it needs to access a local config.json file prior to bootstrapping. How do I allow Azure App Services to serve the config.json file to the AngularJS application?

I have tried creating a virtual directory that matches the file path; I have tried to configure the web.config of the website to serve .json files. I have checked all file paths and also tried to define the full path instead of using a relative path.

```
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    $.get("config/config.json", (response) => {
        angular.module('myApp').config((configurationProvider) => {
            configurationProvider.initialize(response);
        });

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
});
```

The code above works as expected when the application is hosted locally in IIS and IIS Express. However, when the application is deployed to Azure it returns the following message

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. There are two changes that I had to make to ensure that both the application and server request and respond correctly.

First, I've changed the application code to:

```
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    $.getJSON("config/config.json", (response) => {
        angular.module('myApp').config((configurationProvider) => {
            configurationProvider.initialize(response);
        });

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
});
```

Second, I've added a Web.config to the website directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Both are required in Azure App Services.